# Windows 8 app, Bing Maps offline

Tags: windows-8, navigation, geolocation, bing-maps, offline-caching

Is it possible to create a Win8 app that will sync Bing Maps for offline use and still allow for navigation and/or geolocation?

The idea is to run the app on an RT tablet that has a GPS.  The client wishes to download maps to avoid data connectivity costs.  The app will store addresses.  The user will be able to select 1+ addresses to plot on map and navigate either from the current location or a given location.  Voice navigation is a plus, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

No. Bing Maps is not allowed to be used offline.